# Can I control when a launched instance enters the "passed" state?

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2

I launch an instance via the API and poll for when it enters the "passed" state like this:

```
while ( (Get-EC2InstanceStatus -InstanceId $InstanceId -Region $Region).status.Details.status.value -ne 'passed') {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
    'Instance ' + $InstanceId + ": waiting for passed state ($(((Get-Date) - $StartTime).TotalSeconds) elapsed)"          
}
```

I have a script that kicks off (that runs locally on the instance) when the instance is launched and I was wondering if there is a way I could have that script control when the instance enters the passed state.

Is this available from the powershell API?

I was thinking I could have the script postpone the transition to "passed" until it is finished.

Comment: What if the instance ends up in a `failed` state?

Comment: Thats a good point, but not my question.

Comment: Passed is not a valid instance state. Perhaps you're thinking of reachability? I doubt you can control this, but why do you want to?

Comment: How do you mean not valid? It does successfully return "passed".

Comment: Just nitpicking the terminology. It's not an "instance state" (which can only have values pending | running | shutting-down | terminated | stopping | stopped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control even though the feature is not meant for that purpose. The instance state has to be `running` before you can "control" the status. I have not tried this before. Check [ReportInstanceStatus](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ReportInstanceStatus.html)